# Looking for JS library that builds DOM client-side from JSON/object

Tags: javascript, dom

At first glance, it might appear that I'm looking for a simple JS templating engine, but what I'm looking for is more complex. At first I thought about coding this up myself, but the more I think about it, but I can't imagine this hasn't been done before.

Put simply: I am looking for something that will take the following object literal and build the following HTML.

```
{
    tagName   : 'div',
    className : 'container',
    children  :
    [
        {
            tagName   : 'h1',
            className : 'page-title',
            text      : 'My Awesome Page!'
        },
        {
            tagName   : 'a',
            className : 'class-i-gave-to-this-link',
            text      : 'Check out my other awesome page!',
            attr      : 
            {
                href: 'http://my.awesome-page.com/'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired resulting HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-title">My Awesome Page!</h1>
    <a class="class-i-gave-to-this-link" href="http://my.awesome-page.com/">Check out my other awesome page!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: https://github.com/bloopletech/json2html

Answer (score 2):

Here is my crack at a recursive solution:

```
var jsonToHtml = function(node) {
    var tag = document.createElement(node.tagName);
    tag.className = node.className || "";
    if(node.text) {
        tag.innerHTML = node.text;
    }
    if(node.children) {
        for(var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            tag.appendChild(jsonToHtml(node.children[i]));
        }                
    }
    if(node.attr) {
        for(var key in node.attr) {
            tag.setAttribute(key, node.attr[key]);
        }            
    }
    return tag;
};
```

And here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EqAjd/)

Comment: You sir are a BOSS!
I'm still in search of frameworks that have this sort of functionality -- primarily to see "how they implement it," but I was planning on rewriting it myself anyway, and this will make an excellent starting point. Thanks!